How do I stub 'prompt' method twice in my cypress test?
In one test I have to call two stubs in one test but I end up calling first one only.
My test should first create a folder and then rename it. It involves two out-of-cypress prompts which I am stubbing.
Here is folder creation method. It works perfectly fine in a test where I should only create a folder:
 addFolder(folderName) {
    let stub;

    cy.window().then(win => {
      stub = cy.stub(win, 'prompt').returns(folderName)  // types this value 
    })
    
    cy.get(this.addFolderButtonLocator).click()
    
    cy.wrap(stub).should(() => {
      expect(stub).to.have.been.calledWith()
    })

    return this;

  }

Here is folder rename method (calls only stub from first method)
rename(name, newName) {
   
    let stub;

    cy.window().then(win => {
      stub = cy.stub(win, 'prompt').returns(newName)  // types this value 
    })
    
    this.invokeSideMenu(name);
    cy.get(`[data-cy="${name}-rename"]`).click();
    
    cy.wrap(stub).should(() => {
      expect(stub).to.have.been.calledWith()
    })

    return this;
  }

When I attempt to create and then rename a folder, It only runs first stub and an error 'Attempted to wrap prompt which is already wrapped'
What mistake have I done in my code and how do I run 'prompt' stub twice in one test as i have two different prompts?

It's just a typo - compare #1 cy.stub(win, 'prompt') to #2 cy.stub(win, 'window'). So win.window is a property and cannot be stubbed, but win.prompt is a method and can be stubbed.

ok thank you.  how do i stub 'prompt' method twice in one test?

There is a stub.restore() method that resets the win.prompt to it's original value, which you can use after the stub has been checked.
This limits the scope of the stub to each addFolder/rename call. Normally the stub is active until reset at the end of the test by Cypress.
For example
function addFolder(folderName) {
  let stub
  cy.window().then(win => {
    stub = cy.stub(win, 'prompt').returns(folderName)
  })

  // Invoking the stub
  cy.window().then(win => win.prompt('Adding'))

  cy.wrap(stub).should(() => {
    expect(stub).to.have.been.calledWith('Adding')
    stub.restore()
  })
}

function rename(name, newName) {
  let stub
  cy.window().then(win => {
    stub = cy.stub(win, 'prompt').returns(newName) // types this value
  })

  // Invoking the stub
  cy.window().then(win => win.prompt('Renaming'))

  cy.wrap(stub).should(() => {
    expect(stub).to.have.been.calledWith('Renaming')
    stub.restore()
  })
}

addFolder('my-new-folder')
rename('my-new-name')



bravo, my friend. this code works seamlessly. thank you
